# Hessian after coordinate changing

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f\colon \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$.
Let $z=Px$ coordinate changing. $P$ is $n\times n$ constant matrix, $x$ and $z$ are the variables in $\Bbb R^n$.
Does anyone know a formula which express how the Hessian of $f$ changed after this coordinate transform?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the chain rule not work? Note the differential of the linear map is itself.

Comment: I got (P^t)hess(P)

Answer (score 4):

The chain rule is not valid for the second derivative except if the change of variable is linear, that is here the case.

Let $g(z)=f(P^{-1}z)$. The derivative is $Dg_z(H)=Df_{P^{-1}z}P^{-1}H$ and the second derivative is $D^2g_z(H,K)=D^2f_{P^{-1}z}(P^{-1}H,P^{-1}K)$ or $H^THess(g)_zK=H^TP^{-T}Hess(f)_{P^{-1}z}P^{-1}K$, that implies $Hess(g)_z=P^{-T}Hess(f)_{P^{-1}z}P^{-1}$.

EDIT. Answer to @jjjjjj.

If $g(z)=f(\psi(z))$ where $\psi$ is a non-linear diffeomorphism, then, in a critical point, the result is similar; yet, the calculation is completely different.

$Dg_z(h)=Df_{\psi(z)}(D\psi_z(h))$ and

$D^2g_z(h,k)=D^2f_{\psi(z)}(D\psi_z(h),D\psi_z(k))+Df_{\psi(z)}(D^2\psi_z(h,k))$.

If $z$ is critical, that is, $Df_{\psi(z)}=0$, then

$D^2g_z(h,k)=D^2f_{\psi(z)}(D\psi_z(h),D\psi_z(k))$.

Comment: would it be valid at critical points in $z$ space, though, for arbitrary $\phi: x \to z$? That is, points where the $\nabla \phi_z = 0$? Per [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008525/hessian-under-coordinate-transformation-product-rule)

Comment: Hi, I may not have the background to understand your proof, but can you point to a reference which explains $Dg_z(H)=Df_{P^{-1}z}P^{-1}H$ especially what the $H$, and later the $K$ is suppose to refer to?

Comment: @helios321 . As $z$, $H,K\in\mathbb{R}^n$. $Dg_z:H\in\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a linear function; you can see $H$ as $\Delta z$ -a small variation of z-.  $D^2g_z:(H,K)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a bilinear symmetric function; if you see it as a quadratic function, then choose $H=K=\Delta z$. The associated symmetric  matrix is the Hessian matrix ($\dfrac{\partial^2 g}{\partial z_iz_j}(z)$).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a formula for hess(Ax) where A is a constant matrix.  It comes out to be A^T Hess(x) A.  You can use the chain rule to get there.  It is also helpful to realize that the hessian is the Jacobian of the gradient.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)