# The second derivative test fails but can it succeed after a coordinate transformation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For scalar functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ if the second derivative test fails, could it succeed after a coordinate transformation on $f$ expressed in the new coordinate system?  If so provide example?  If not, explain why.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm guessing this might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359851/hessian-after-coordinate-changing/1181358?noredirect=1#comment7334092_1181358

find some sort of relationship between the hessians, like they are similar matrices - but unsure.

Comment: At a critical point (only), they are related by the equation $H’ = PHP^\top$. They are similar as bilinear forms, not as linear transformations.

Comment: @TedShifrin Not too sure then, not very good at coming up with examples, please help

Comment: The point is that $\det H' = 0$ if and only if $\det H = 0$, so if  the second derivative test fails in one coordinate system, then it fails in any other.