# Second Order Change of Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, change-of-variable, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to simplify a Hessian computation and came across the statement in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359851/hessian-after-coordinate-changing) that a second order change of variables only works for linear changes. I tried looking in some differential geometry books and found in "Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry Vol. 2" on page 201...

"Our Hessian is defined even at points were $f_\ast\neq 0$ because we are working with a vector space and identifying it with its tangent space at $v$; this amounts to saying we are only considering linear changes of coordinates, all of which leave the quantity defined by this formula invariant."

Why isn't there a nonlinear version of the change of variables? With sufficient local information about a function, it seems we should be able to construct the best quadratic approximation. Are there some conditions we can impose to allow for a theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a function $f(y^1, \dots, y^n)$ and a change of variables $y = \Phi(x^1, \dots, x^m)$, then by differentiating twice, using the chain rule as needed, you can certainly get a formula for the Hessian of $f\circ\Phi$ in terms of the first and second derivatives of $f$ and $\Phi$. It just won't be as nice and simple as the one for the Jacobian. The formula does become nice at a critical point of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, Deane. Perhaps I was being too literal.

Comment: One point is that the Hessian is often treated as a bilinear form, but it does *not* transform like a bilinear form under nonlinear change of coordinates. If you want to define a coordinate-independent notion of the second derivative, one must use a more complicated object such as a covariant Hessian or $2$-jet.